# What is the __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR good for (MSVC map file)?

Tags: visual-c++, dictionary, linker, executable, coff

I have a map file generated with microsoft visual studio. It contains a relatively big area named __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR. What is this good for? It has something to do with linked dlls but I cannot figure out the exact purpose of it.

Comment: Did you ever find more information on this token? I'm struggling with the same question, and can't seem to find much relevant info on the web.

Comment: No, I'm also still stuck on the meaning of this stuff but I suspect it is some place reservation for linking purposes... But sorry, no definitively sure from where it comes and if how to make the images smaller (embedded software)

Comment: I have learned about this when trying from the linker log: http://goo.gl/6w8NC. I wonder if I can get rid of those warnings?

Answer (score 2):

__NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR is the IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR structure. With all its fields set to null it indicates the end of the IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR array in the imports section. It takes only 20 bytes.